# postgresql: "...where X IN <array type column values>" syntax?

Tags: postgresql

I'm having problem with using the values of an array column in a where clause. Complete example to reproduce:

```
create type public.genre_type as enum ('scifi', 'fantasy', 'crime', 'horror', 'classics');
create table public.reader_profile(
    id integer,
    fave_genres genre_type ARRAY
);
create table public.books(
    id serial not null,
    title text,
    genre_type public.genre_type
);
insert into public.reader_profile(id, fave_genres) values (1, array['crime', 'horror']::public.genre_type[]);
insert into public.reader_profile(id, fave_genres) values (2, array['fantasy', 'scifi']::public.genre_type[]);
insert into public.reader_profile(id, fave_genres) values (3, array['scifi', 'classics']::public.genre_type[]);
insert into public.books(title, genre_type) values ('gone with the wind', 'classics');
insert into public.books(title, genre_type) values ('Foundation', 'scifi');
insert into public.books(title, genre_type) values ('Dune', 'scifi');

-- THE FOLLOWING FAILS!!!
select * from public.books
  where genre_type in (
      select fave_genres from public.reader_profile where id = 2
  );
```

I've tried `...where genre_type = ANY()` per other stackoverflow answers as well as `...where genre_type <@ ()` and I can't get anything to work! It seems the inner query (which works) is being return as an array type and not a list of values or something. Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Hogan that this seems doable with a `JOIN` but the syntax you are looking for is the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM books
WHERE genre_type = ANY(ARRAY(SELECT fave_genres FROM reader_profile WHERE id = 2))
;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5a3a57f86d7cb0fc5fc5795aeb432f4c)

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest using a join instead?

```
select * 
from public.books b
join public.reader_profile fg on b.genre_type = ANY(rp.fave_genres) and fg.id = 2
```

Comment: oh...! This is nice too! Thanks v much!!! I guess I'll still accept the first answer because it best illustrates what I was doing wrong. I'm gonna investigate both approaches tho. The actual query already has a lot of joins but yeah what's one more, eh? haha